# Redirect based on user type in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I'm planning to redirect users from opening the login page if already login. I got that working. However, I must redirect to different pages based on their user role.

This is the working code. It redirects to /admin/dashboard if someone opens this page.

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public user = {}  as {email?: string; password?: string; };
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
      if (this.authService.session.isActive) {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard']);
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  login() {
    this.authService.login(`${this.user.email}:${this.user.password}`).subscribe(data => {
      const token: Token =  {token: data.token} as Token;
      this.authService.saveToken(token);
      this.authService.session.token = token;
      this.authService.session.isActive = true;
      this.authService.session.profile = data.user as Profile;
      this.authService.saveProfile(this.authService.session.profile);
      if (data.user.role === 'admin') {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard']);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin/submissions']);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I want to redirect based on user type, and so made the following modifications but it's not working:

```
if (this.authService.session.isActive && data.user.role  === 'admin') {
      this.router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard']);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/admin/submissions']);
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

How do I resolve this issue?

I already tried this:

```
this.authService.login(`${this.user.email}:${this.user.password}`).subscribe(data => {
      if (this.authService.session.isActive && data.user.role === 'admin') {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard']);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/admin/submissions']);
      }
    });
```

and got the following response error:

```
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
```

Comment: You don't have `data` outside of the subcription to the `login` call, where did you think it would come from in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, I tried but failed to get it working.

Comment: Couldn't get *what* to work? Give a [mcve].

Comment: I already gave the minimal reproducible example: `if (this.authService.session.isActive && data.user.role  === 'admin') {
      this.router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard']);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/admin/submissions']);
    }`

Comment: But that's clearly not going to work for the reason above, your example should be halfway plausible at least. Trivially: data is undefined because you haven't defined data. Maybe you can get it back from the auth service, but we can't see that implementation.

Comment: code where you want to try ? can you give that details ? second block of code ?

Comment: I don't know where to put the data so it's `inside` the subscription. Hence, I asked showcasing the error too.

Comment: There's no second block of code. I know I have to place the `data` inside the subscription but can't figure out how. What I pasted is the entire .TS file.

Comment: Yes you do, because you're already accessing data inside the subscription. But that only happens inside login, which by default must be after the constructor gets called. I'd suggest reading https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication, which gives a totally different way of approaching this; a component constructor isn't a good place to do work.

Comment: I updated the question with the error.

Comment: Well that shouldn't be surprising, because this.user starts as an empty object; username and password are both undefined in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if (this.authService.session.isActive && this.authService.session.profile.role  === 'admin') {
      this.router.navigate(['/admin/dashboard']);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/admin/submissions']);
    }
```

try this in ngOnInit()

You will one redirection logic inside ngOnInit() before login does. If session is active this will check and do their job.

Comment: Thanks. I did this and it works but the login page isn't showing up anymore after I logout.

Comment: you can put in logout function to redirect.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks.